# How does “uses” and “duration” apply to Wonder Woman’s bracers and Superman’s suit in DC Heroes?

Tags: armor, supers, dc-heroes

In **DC Heroes** (first edition, 1985), Wonder Woman (*Gamemaster’s Manual*, page 80) has, under equipment, her “Bracers” with “Uses 10: Duration: 15". Superman (page 79) has his “Super Uniform” with “Uses: 4, Duration: 26”.

I see a description of uses and durations for buildings (page 29), vehicles (page 32), and weapons (page 33), but I don’t grok how that applies to bracers or the suit.

From the description of buildings and weapons, this would seem to mean that Wonder Woman can use her bracers for up to 10 days (10 uses, and duration 15 is 1 day), after which maintenance is required? Superman can use his suit for up to thirty-two years (4 uses, and duration 26 is 8 years), after which maintenance is required?

The note about duration on page 28 for “ordinary gadgets” implies that the uses must be tracked when in actual use—that is, Wonder Woman would only count the few seconds of combat time per day that she uses her bracers. But the note about duration on page 25 describes uses as “the number of times the gadget can be used” and describes duration in terms of "gadgets that mimic Attributes and Automatic Actions (like Running, Flight, Swimming)” or “gadgets that mimic Standard Actions (like Starbolt, Bio-Blast, etc.)”.

Because Force Shields (Wonder Woman’s bracers) are “Type: Automatic”, does this mean the player tracks the actual combat time that the bracers are in use? Seems like they would last forever. Skin Armor (Superman’s suit) are also automatic (and the suit’s Body is an attribute), so the player technically would track the amount of use the suit gets?

In both cases, it seems as though tracking is unnecessary unless there’s some sort of time travel involved, as, especially in the case of Superman’s suit the time used will never in normal game time reach the uses times the duration.

The section on armor in the *Player’s Manual*, page 24, does not mention uses or duration.

How does uses and duration affect Wonder Woman’s use of her bracers, or Superman’s use of his suit?

Answer (score 3):

Page 4 explains how time is measured with AP. Page 25 explains how gadgets work.

There are two types of gadgets, ordinary and special
Each gadget has a specific number of Charges or Uses (the terms are interchangeable).

There's different rules for Attributes and Automatic Actions differentiated from Standard Actions.

If it's the first type, Duration is the APs the gadget will work once it is turned on.
For gadgets that mimic Standard Actions the Charges are used up in one phase of time, there is no Duration.

Once all the Charges are used up, the gadget has to be fitted with  a Reload Pack  which completely recharges a gadget up to the limit of its Uses.

Wonder Woman has 10 uses before gadget requires maintenance. That means she can use the gadget ten times, not ten days. It'll work for 15 AP which is 60 seconds. (1 AP being 4 seconds.) Superman's Uniform is armor that lasts 104 seconds (26 AP) each time he uses it, and it can be used 4 times.
(Boov: 261 Uses: 4, Duration: 26, Skin Armor: 10)

Comment: I can’t see on page 25 of the GM Manual where APs for gadgets that have a Duration are different than non-gadget Durations. “Batman’s Batmobile has 9 Uses (or Charges), and each Charge has a Duration of 13 APs of time (or about 8 hours). In other words, Batman can run the Batmobile for 8 hours before it will need to refuel and do this 9 times before he needs a tune-up.” If a gadget with Duration 13 lasts 8 hours/use, wouldn’t a gadget with Duration 15 last 1 day per use, and a gadget with Duration 26  for 8 years per use? That’s where I got the numbers in my question.

Comment: On page 15 of core rulebook it reads "TIME: Combat is always measured in phases. One round of Combat lasts one phase, which equals 0 APs or 4 seconds". On Page 4 of the GM manual you have a table that confirms that 1 AP is 4 seconds.
In page 40 of the player's manual you'll see that there is a special table for Vehicles, so it is correct that 15 AP is 1 day, in the vehicles chart. If we talk about a character, 1 AP is 4 seconds.